# Pack and Unpack Bits and Bytes in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python (I'm using Python3) and programming in general. Could you please provide a detailed explanation on how pack and unpack produce an answer in python; I know the syntax for using both functions but I do not understand how the answer is calculated. For example, I do not understand why the following code:

`L = struct.pack('f', 255)
print([ii for ii in L])`

would produce the following output (especially why there is 127 and 67):

`[0, 0, 127, 67]`

Also, why the following code:

`LL = struct.unpack('i', b'0000')
print(LL)`

would produce the following number:

`(808464432,)`

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you are new to Python and new to programming entirely, packing `struct`s is a painful choice for a beginner task. Try starting with something simpler, like a program that tells you whether each number in a range of values is divisible by 3, 5, or both (commonly known as "FizzBuzz").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case you're seeing the decimal values of the 4 bytes that make up a [32bit floating point number](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html).

In your specific example, the floating point number 255.0 is represented in memory as 4 bytes with hexadecimal values of `43 7f 00 00`. Since you're on a [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) platform, you see the least significant byte first. Hence, converted into a list of bytes, you have

```
[ 0x00, 0x00, 0x7f, 0x43 ]
```

Converted to decimal values you obtain

```
[0, 0, 127, 67]
```

---

In the second case, you try to interpret the result of `b'0000'`.

```
>>> type(b'0000')
<class 'bytes'>
>>> len(b'0000')
4
```

As you can see, this expression returns a sequence of 4 bytes, so in this case it will be a sequence of 4 instances of the character `0`.

```
>>> '%x' % ord('0')
'30'
```

The value of the character `0` is `0x30` in hexadecimal. The 4 bytes interpreted as a 32bit integer are equivalent to the hexadecimal value of `0x30303030`.

```
>>> 0x30303030
808464432
```

When we write this value in decimal, we obtain `808464432`.